# MySql Prepare sql statement for search filter

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

I have a Sql SP that applies filter based on parms being passed to the SP.
it works if i just pass valid values like (2,4) in example below.
but if no filter is passed it should return all rows. **Problem is checking for 
parmIndustryId is null or for parmIndustryId is '' empty string, without that it works but i need to be able to check for empty string or null.**

> **this is the error i get**
>   Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1
>   column(s) 0.000 sec

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `SearchIndustry`(
         IN  parmIndustryId TEXT     
    )
BEGIN
 SET parmIndustryId ='2,4';

 set @sql = CONCAT(' Select t1.*  
  FROM  Industry t1 
  WHERE Active =1 AND(', parmIndustryId ,' is null OR t2.IndustryId IN( ', parmIndustryId, ' ))')

    ;

PREPARE q FROM @sql;
execute q;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

**How Can i correctly pass value for IN operand filter?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Industry
WHERE Active = 1 
  AND (parmIndustryId IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET(IndustryId, parmIndustryId))
```

---

Edit, you may need to also use `COALESCE` if empty strings can be passed.  If so, this will work:

```
 SELECT *
 FROM Industry
 WHERE Active = 1 
    AND (COALESCE($parmIndustryId,'') = '' 
             OR FIND_IN_SET(IndustryId, $parmIndustryId));
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c36e/1)

Comment: but that will not use any index